# What attribute determines the text color for MaterialTextView element in Material Design 3?

Tags: android, textview, material-design

In the XML layout using Material Design 3, I have a MaterialTextView element that dynamically takes its color from the Material Design 3 theme. However, I am unsure which attribute is responsible for determining the text color of the MaterialTextView element. I attempted to retrieve the current text color of the MaterialTextView element in Java and convert it to hexadecimal, but the color returned does not match any values in colors.xml. because of that I want to know which attribute is responsible for determining the text color of the MaterialTextView element.

The MaterialTextView exists inside the MaterialCardView.

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="seed">#6750A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_primary">#6750A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_primaryContainer">#EADDFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onPrimaryContainer">#21005D</color>
    <color name="md_theme_secondary">#625B71</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSecondary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_secondaryContainer">#E8DEF8</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSecondaryContainer">#1D192B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_tertiary">#7D5260</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onTertiary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_tertiaryContainer">#FFD8E4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onTertiaryContainer">#31111D</color>
    <color name="md_theme_error">#B3261E</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onError">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_errorContainer">#F9DEDC</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onErrorContainer">#410E0B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_outline">#79747E</color>
    <color name="md_theme_background">#FFFBFE</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onBackground">#1C1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surface">#FFFBFE</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSurface">#1C1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surfaceVariant">#E7E0EC</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSurfaceVariant">#49454F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inverseSurface">#313033</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inverseOnSurface">#F4EFF4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inversePrimary">#D0BCFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surfaceTint">#6750A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_outlineVariant">#CAC4D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_scrim">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

**night/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="md_theme_primary">#D0BCFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onPrimary">#381E72</color>
    <color name="md_theme_primaryContainer">#4F378B</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onPrimaryContainer">#EADDFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_secondary">#CCC2DC</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSecondary">#332D41</color>
    <color name="md_theme_secondaryContainer">#4A4458</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSecondaryContainer">#E8DEF8</color>
    <color name="md_theme_tertiary">#EFB8C8</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onTertiary">#492532</color>
    <color name="md_theme_tertiaryContainer">#633B48</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onTertiaryContainer">#FFD8E4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_error">#F2B8B5</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onError">#601410</color>
    <color name="md_theme_errorContainer">#8C1D18</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onErrorContainer">#F9DEDC</color>
    <color name="md_theme_outline">#938F99</color>
    <color name="md_theme_background">#1C1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onBackground">#E6E1E5</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surface">#1C1B1F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSurface">#E6E1E5</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surfaceVariant">#49454F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_onSurfaceVariant">#CAC4D0</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inverseSurface">#E6E1E5</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inverseOnSurface">#313033</color>
    <color name="md_theme_inversePrimary">#6750A4</color>
    <color name="md_theme_shadow">#000000</color>
    <color name="md_theme_surfaceTint">#D0BCFF</color>
    <color name="md_theme_outlineVariant">#49454F</color>
    <color name="md_theme_scrim">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_theme_primary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/md_theme_onPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_primaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/md_theme_onPrimaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/md_theme_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/md_theme_onSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondaryContainer">@color/md_theme_onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorTertiary">@color/md_theme_tertiary</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiary">@color/md_theme_onTertiary</item>
        <item name="colorTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_tertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnTertiaryContainer">@color/md_theme_onTertiaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/md_theme_error</item>
        <item name="colorErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_errorContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">@color/md_theme_onError</item>
        <item name="colorOnErrorContainer">@color/md_theme_onErrorContainer</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_background</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/md_theme_onBackground</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_surface</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_onSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_surfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/md_theme_onSurfaceVariant</item>
        <item name="colorOutline">@color/md_theme_outline</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_inverseOnSurface</item>
        <item name="colorSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_inverseSurface</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryInverse">@color/md_theme_inversePrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Java**

```
Log.w("ABC", Integer.toHexString(materialTextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor())); \\Output is ffcac4d0
```

I changed `<color name="md_theme_onSurfaceVariant">#CAC4D0</color>` to another color to check if MaterialTextView will change or not, but it did not change. So, the color `#cac4d0` does not come from `md_theme_onSurfaceVariant`. I want to know where this hex color `#cac4d0` is coming from.

I'm testing the app in dark mode.